# Declined rude or abusive flags

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

There's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51639234/503046) that's collected quite a comment thread. Two of the comments are, IMAO, against community standards. As non-American-non-native English speaker, I would like to have clarification if I didn't quite understood the tone and used inappropriate flags.

The flags were "Rude or abusive", but both were rejected. I would like to know why. The flagged comments are belittling and, I would say, portrait their poster as a jerk.

First one, flagged-and-rejected:

> You have at least two lines of invalid syntax in your batch file. If
>   you read the help for the IF command you should see that your
>   IF...ELSE syntax is incorrect. Also the line that begins with %%i
>   should throw a syntax error because I am pretty sure the computer name
>   is not a valid command.

To me, this is not a constructive comment. Instead of explaining the error, it merely tells the OP to read documentation. This is quite passive-aggressive, akin to saying "I know what's the problem, but am not going to tell you." Is this appropriate a way to talk in person with someone one respects, or am I reading too much in it?

The OP asks for details:

> Where's the mistake? Here's the Microsoft help page:
>   docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/…

And gets another passive-aggressive reply, flagged-and-rejected. This is a bit more constructive, as it hints to more details. But should one play twenty questions anyway?

> Open up a command prompt and type: IF /?. In regards to the link you
>   posted you should be able to see it clear as day. Third and fourth
>   example

The OP seems to be annoyed, and rightly so:

> These recommendations are not helpful if you are seeing a clear syntax
>   error. Call out the apparent mistake already.

So, to sum up: where did I go wrong with the flags?

Comment: As I always feared, we're going to exaggerate about the definition of _rudeness_.

Comment: Yay~ my favorite pastime (in a monotone voice)

Comment: ***whoa.*** That first comment simply tells you what is wrong. how is that rude or abusive? if anything it's helpful.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that first comment. I could have been the author of that.

Comment: I don't really read those comments as passive-aggressive. Perhaps because few words are used , some may see it as rudish, but it doesn't really sound that aggressive/rude to me. Referring to the third and fourth example of a page is also a helpful note.

Comment: I guess the definition of rude is whenever the commenter does not massage the OP's back and give him/her $100.

Comment: Btw, the comment ^^ that I just posted. *That's* an example of a non-constructive comment.

Comment: *Instead of explaining the error, it merely tells the OP to read documentation.* But the comment *does* explain that the OP's IF ELSE syntax is incorrect and also points out the exact location of another syntax error. How is that not an explanation?

Comment: @Mysticial:  Once you put money on the table you could've gone in any direction from there.  I'm grateful you went the direction you did.

Comment: Another lump of evidence for the efficacy of never commenting on questions from low-rep users.  Overall, it's just not worth the hassle for curators.  If you want to be sure of not receiving r/a flags, be sure to not comment.

Comment: While not as helpful as it *could* be, I think the first comment is fine. The second one though... I'm not a huge fan of "you should be able to see it clear as day." That part should be edited out. Not sure it reaches the level of "rude or abusive", but it's definitely not necessary to be that dismissive of new users.

Comment: The can worms has been opened.

Comment: My teaching style is to lead the horse to water.  Teach the man to fish.  You can tell someone 22 times how to do something and they will never remember until you force them to do their own research.  I have literally gone back to people's other questions on StackOverFlow and DosTip.com and found responses to a previous question they asked that were exactly the same.   So if you want a reason as to why I do what I do, there it is. The answer was dead on in help file and the OP eventually understood that and commented.  I am sorry if this hurt your feelings.

Comment: The first comment is seems like a perfect example of pointing them in the right direction, which is a better way to teach someone than spoon-feeding, although that's not really what comments are for - this is a question and answer site, not a question, answer and general guidance site (you may have had more luck flagging it as "no longer whatever the new text for this reason isn't needed").

Comment: I find it rude that you are saying that the people who wrote these comments were being rude and abusive.

Comment: By this standard, I can't talk in my office without being rude anymore.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I declined those flags. The fine answers [by Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371898/2057919) and [by Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371899/2057919) already explain the basic reasoning pretty well, but I'll offer a little more explanation by breaking down the comments in question.

## Comment #1

Let's take it one sentence at a time.

> You have at least two lines of invalid syntax in your batch file.

This is just a statement of fact. (I didn't check to see if it's a *correct* fact; that's not what moderators look for when reviewing flags.)

> If you read the help for the IF command you should see that your IF...ELSE syntax is incorrect.

This is also just a statement of fact. "If you read the help" is maybe a *little* [passive-aggressive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passive-aggressive). But it's not nearly on the level of "RTFM, you [expletives] idiot," which is the kind of thing we see far too often. The latter is the kind of thing that should be flagged "rude or abusive." "If you read the help" is, arguably, just somebody trying to point the OP in the right direction.

> Also the line that begins with %%i should throw a syntax error because I am pretty sure the computer name is not a valid command.

Again, maybe a *little* passive-aggressive after the word "because," but it's mostly just pointing out what is going wrong.

All in all, the tone isn't pitch-perfect, but it's a pretty helpful comment. **Conclusion: not rude or abusive, flag declined.**

## Comment #2

> Open up a command prompt and type: IF /?.

This is just an instruction. A little bossy, but hardly an abuse of commenting privileges.

> In regards to the link you posted you should be able to see it clear as day.

This is, again, perhaps a *little* passive-aggressive in the "clear as day" bit. But not really. Mostly, this is just an explanation of where to find relevant information.

> Third and fourth example.

At first, this seems wildly out of place. What is this? When you reread it, though, it's clear that the commenter is saying, "The third and fourth examples at the link you posted are the ones you [OP] should review; they explain what's wrong with your code." In other words, the comment gives a roadmap directly to the pertinent help information. In light of this, the previous sentence looks even less offensive.

Again, a helpful comment, even if it's a little bossy. **Conclusion: not rude or abusive, flag declined.**

## A Note on Annoyed OPs

You wrote,

> The OP seems to be annoyed, and rightly so:
>
> > These recommendations are not helpful if you are seeing a clear syntax error. Call out the apparent mistake already.

OP was definitely annoyed. But we don't determine whether something is rude or abusive by whether it annoyed somebody; we only ask whether *it is* rude or abusive. And the comments *did* point out at least one clear syntax error (`%%i`). OP's interpretation of the comments is not dispositive.

## Summary

Several users in that comment thread probably should work a bit on their tone and style. But, as you know, not everyone is a native speaker of English, and tone is really, really hard to get right in a comment on the Internet. We cut people a lot of slack for that kind of thing.

Please continue to flag profanity, "RTFM," outright insults ("moron," "child," "son of a motherless goat," etc.), and that kind of thing. But there's no need to flag things that are simply a little brusque.

Comment: Thanks [for declining these flags].

Comment: Good to see at least someone still has their head on straight and won't succumb to the current trend of playing rudeness cards like they're candy.

Comment: @Gimby yup - time for a candy crush.

Comment: I'm kind of curious what other mods would say about these. The second one seem to be very much along the lines of the comments that was in that blog post a while back. If that one is fine, but the ones in the blog post aren't, I'm probably mostly just confused. Although maybe I'm not remembering them so well.

Comment: @Dukeling I can't speak for others, but the voting on this thread (+0/-59 on the question, +29/-0 on my answer, at the time of this comment) seems to indicate a pretty solid consensus. I *do* think context matters, which is one reason the bluntness - not rudeness, just directness - of the second comment is unworthy of a "rude or abusive" flag. The commenter, an experienced user, pointed to some obvious problems with the script, and the OP - the person having problems - responded immediately with "are you sure?" We expect people not to lash out, but we don't ask people to sugar-coat everything.

Comment: @Dukeling, I do agree completely with Ed's answer. FWIW, The welcoming movement is to encourage users to flag abusive comments and not about moderators to be more lenient in terms of what we consider as rude. The blog does not change any policies on the site regarding rude comments, as such. The changes to the CoC, OTOH, does.

Comment: @EdCottrell I mean, you yourself even say it's "a little passive-aggressive". So you agree that it's offensive, but not offensive enough to offend anyone (or "a reasonable person"?). I'm not going to argue about the validity of drawing that line, I'm just pointing out that it just seems like people are going back and forth about what's fine and what isn't, which is confusing. Also, I don't trust community votes much - I've seen too many cases (including this one) where 2 posts say essentially the same thing and one gets upvoted to infinity and the other gets downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @Dukeling What I meant was that portions of it could be *understood* as offensive, if one (1) interprets it as passive-aggressive and (2) finds that offensive (not everyone would or does). Even in the worst possible light, though - assuming the commenter is a fluent speaker of English and *wanted* to be rude - any rudeness was very, very mild, and the comments were still pretty helpful. We would delete or edit a helpful comment with true rudeness (“RTFM,” insults, etc.), but we’re not going to do so for a comment that *might* rub some readers the wrong way if they kind of squint at it.

Comment: @Dukeling You can find just about any phrase as passive aggressive if you're trying to be offended.  `I mean, you yourself even say it's "a little passive-aggressive".` Are you subtly trying to imply that I'm a hypocrite for contradicting myself? `I'm not going to argue about the validity of drawing that line,` Oh, so you think you're so much better than me, aren't you? `Also, I don't trust community votes much ` You're passively insulting a moderator of this community saying that their community isn't working right! ... Okay so you didn't mean any of this, but someone can read it that way.

Comment: However, phrases here like "Clear as day" probably just mean "if you follow my instructions, it will be easy to see" not the passive aggressive implication "Since you aren't doing this, you must be so blind that you can't see something as obvious as the sun at noon-day." It's only offensive or passive-aggressive or whatever form of unwelcomingness we want to project onto the words if we make it that way.

Comment: @DavyM I was trying to say "You say this is fine, but you also don't and it's like those other things 'you' previously said weren't fine", not "This is fine" (because arguing about the "fine-ness" of this would basically come down to eliciting empathy, which can be really hard).

Answer (score 19):

Explaining the underlying concepts that the question author doesn't know that is preventing them from solving their problem, or providing someone with debugging tips to help them figure out how to solve their problem is not rude.  Just giving someone some code to copy-paste without them learning anything about what happened, how to fix their problem, and teaching them how to correct the issue when they face it in the future is what's inappropriate.  That's not actually a helpful response.

Remember that SO exists *to create a repository of knowledge*, not to provide free coding consultations.  The purpose of the site is to take problems that do not have readily available high quality solutions, and provide a solution to that problem.  An not just for the one person asking about it right now, but for *all of the other people who have that same problem* who are now able to find it via a web search, or the same person when they have the same problem next week even.

So trying to actually *teach* someone something, rather than giving them code to copy-paste, is not only not rude, it's *what a good answer entails*.  Even if that's not what the author (or you) want to hear.  Telling someone something they don't want to hear is not necessarily rude.

Answer (score 16):

Rude language indicates that someone is making a remark with no tactical bearing on the question, and is directly engaging with the OP in inflammatory remarks.  Saying, "Go read the documentation, it's plain as day right there you dummy" is enough to rise to the level of "rude".

Abusive language indicates highly inflammatory or wanton offensive language hurled at the OP as opposed to having anything to do with the question.  Remarks about their intelligence, race, culture, creed or sex could be considered abusive.

Since ***none*** of these comments seem to rise to either level, I could see a justification as to why none of these were actioned, since *absent context*, they don't seem that bad.

That's not to say that the entire comment chain won't just magically disappear overnight...which would be good for all involved.

Comment: "In regards to the link you posted you should be able to see it clear as day" - you should be able to see clear as day that this is rather condescending (clearly it wasn't clear for the other person, so it could roughly be interpreted as "I'm so much better than you because it was clear as day to me and you can't even see it"). The comment as a whole may be helpful, but it's still rude (although I have no idea why the first comment might be considered rude).

Comment: @Dukeling take the same argument you used for the clear as day, push it to a bit more extreme stance, and reread 'if you read the help [...] You should see'.  It can sound as paternalizing as 'clear as day'. I completely disagree with it being rude, but I guess that is the reasoning or feeling that sparked this question.  As Mysticial said, maybe we need to give money for each comments now so users won't think we're rude....